# How to set limit on Mongodb returning documents?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, api, aggregation-framework, limit

I've created an API. I've a problem here. I want to set the limits on the `Fields` of each document to return.

**API:**

```
const Pipeline = 
          [{
                '$search': {
                    'text': {
                        'query': `${text}`,
                        'path': 'title',
                    }
                }       
          },
          { 
            '$limit': 5 
          }]
var result = await collection.aggregate(pipeline).toArray();
response.status(200).send(result);
```

**My response from server:**

```
  {
    "_id": "039x39sd939hlf",
    "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli",
    "brand": "Pogoplug",
    "type": "Online data entry",
    "price": 69,
    "description": "giat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occa"
  },
  {
    "_id": "039x39sd939hlf",
    "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli",
    "brand": "Pogoplug",
    "type": "Online data backup",
    "price": 69,
    "description": "giat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occa"
  }
```

Now, I've to limit it like this:
**Expected Result:**

```
  {
    "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli",
    "brand": "Peppa Pig",

  },
  {
    "name": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing eli",
    "brand": "Pogoplug",
  },
```

Which aggregation should I use which is fast and make this possible??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage to return only fields you want, like this:

```
const Pipeline = 
[
  {
   /*your current pipeline*/
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "name": 1,
      "brand": 1
    }
  }
]
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/0nCEELjGtl5)